# How to render updated list after updating a filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever, user is checking the checkbox, the `factoryQuery` array is getting updated.
Search function is for filtering `procurements` array. I want the `ProcurementList` component to call search whenever factoryQuery is getting changed.

Search Function:

```
const search = () => {
        if(factoryQuery.length != 0){
        return procurements.filter(
            (procurement) =>
                factoryQuery.includes(procurement.data.factory_name.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
            return procurements; 
        }  
    };
```

Function called on checking a checkBox

```
const handleCheck = (e) => {
        var array = factoryQuery;
        if(e.target.checked){
            array.push(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
        }else{
            if(array.indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1){
            array.splice(array.indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()), 1);  
            }
        }
        setFactoryQuery(array);
    }
```

Component to render Procurements List:

```
<ProcurementsList procurements={search(procurements)} />
```

Comment: `search(procurements)` here you pass `procurements` to `search()` function, but the function doesn't take any params.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the search method inside a useEffect hook and add factoryQuery in dependency array , that way it rerenders everytime factoryQuery changs